Execute Jmeter ,jmx file using Selenium
I want to execute my jmeter file in my framework using Selenium Java
public void runJmeter(String jmxFilePath, String rptOutPutFolder) throws Exception{
        JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity", "60000");
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:\\Softwares\\jmeter\\apache-jmeter-5.6.3\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\Softwares\\jmeter\\apache-jmeter-5.6.3\\bin");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // Initialize JMeter engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
        File jmxFile = new File(jmxFilePath);
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmxFile);

        // Run JMeter Test Plan
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();

        generateReport("path/to/jmeter/bin", rptOutPutFolder);
    }

    private void generateReport(String jmeterHome, String reportOutputFolder) throws Exception {
        // Configure JMeter for report generation
        JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity", "60000");
        JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title", "JMeter Test Report");
        JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.classname", "org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter");

        // Ensure the output folder exists
        File reportDir = new File(reportOutputFolder);
        if (!reportDir.exists()) {
            reportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // Generate the report
        ReportGenerator reportGenerator = new ReportGenerator("C:\\Softwares\\jmeter\\apache-jmeter-5.6.3\\bin\\jmeter.properties", null);
        reportGenerator.generate();
    }

